# Get the value from a SOAP message in Java

Tags: java, parsing, soap

I am getting a SOAP message as a string after making a call to the web service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <PassOracleXMLDataResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <PassOracleXMLDataResult>
                <gesystem xmlns="">
                    <return_code>0</return_code>
                    <message>PRS User does not exists in GETS</message>
                    <invoiceid>TESTADDTLINFO2</invoiceid>
                    <datetime>Apr 17 2013  4:19PM</datetime>
                </gesystem>
            </PassOracleXMLDataResult>
        </PassOracleXMLDataResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I need to retrieve the values  and  elements. When I tried to use a simple SAXBuilder to build a Document and traverse it, I got an exception after trying to getChild on "soap: Body"

```
getChild("soap:Body") - returns null.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using JDOM:

soap:Body is actually two parts: the namespace and the element name. You'll want to use the Namespace class to include that information when retrieving it.

Try doing something like:

```
envelopeNode.getChild("Body",envelopeNode.getNamespace());
```

That'll make it look for the child element with the name "Body", and the same namespace as the envelope node.

Comment: Thanks Peter, it worked. There is only one strange thing. When I was getting a child Element for "PassOracleXMLDataResult" it also required to provide a Namespace as a second parameter./n                                   Namespace nmspc = Namespace.getNamespace("http://tempuri.org/");    
                Element parseResponse = bodyEm.getChild("PassOracleXMLDataResponse", nmspc);            
                Element passResult = parseResponse.getChild("PassOracleXMLDataResult", nmspc);

Comment: Right; my example just uses the namespace of the parent element (in this case, "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/". Since PassOracleXMLDataResponse is in a different namspace ("http://tempuri.org/"), you'd need to pass that one to getChild(), not the parents'.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Peter, it worked. There is only one strange thing. When I was getting a child Element for "PassOracleXMLDataResult" it also required to provide a Namespace as a second parameter

```
                Namespace nmspc = Namespace.getNamespace("http://tempuri.org/");    
            Element parseResponse = bodyEm.getChild("PassOracleXMLDataResponse", nmspc);            
            Element passResult = parseResponse.getChild("PassOracleXMLDataResult", nmspc);
```

Comment: I suppose this is because it need the full node identification, that contains namespaces too.